# Tableau - Date Filter that acts on Two Date Columns

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set that we are pulling from two different SQL tables. This is a custom SQL query. This is financial data - trades and transactions. I am pulling them together in a single return so for each customer I can see all the trades and transactions in a single query. To be specific - some trades do not have corresponding transactions, and some transactions do not have corresponding trades - therefore there are some rows that will have both a trade AND transaction date, some will have one or the other. For those missing they are NULL.

My question is - how can I create a filter so that I get all trades and transactions in a given date range? I tried using two filters (one for each date), but for some reason that won't work. Also, I'd like for our customers to be able to have one filter that gives them any trade or transaction in that range.

I thought about a parameter, but with the data always changing (this gets refreshed daily), I need something dynamic - one filter that will filter the data set on those two fields. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Please provide more information (ex: sample data set, etc) for us to help you. As such from the information available, its unclear that trades and transactions are date type, string type or float type value.

Comment: I can't share any data, it is sensitive information, however, I can tell you that is that trades (trading information) is one table and transactions (customer transactions in and out of the account) are two different tables. Each have their own date of when that trade or transaction was performed. The dates are standard "2018-01-01" date format.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand me. I asked for a sample data set wherein you could have filled values for the fields. Main idea is to understand the structure/schema of your data set so as to work with those to give you a viable answer. From the latest comment, I gather that you want to fetch data and want to filter on 2 different dates for all the data. This is not possible in the essence that your joining field is CustomerID or name and not the date. Therefore when you apply filters, you will get the data in both the tables completely for that date range for the customers.

Comment: One way to achieve what you want is to create a combined dataset that has a **single** date field (EventDate) and another that classifies which event happened on that date (trade or transaction). Then, when you filter by date, you get all the events in that date range. These can be linked by the unique ID of the transaction or trade to recover the full details 9or just build a custom label containing all the detail as well as the dates).